# Editing a table field used for sorting

Tags: angularjs, sorting, focus

I have a table of entities like

```
<tr ng-repeat="e in entities">
    <td ng-repeat="c in columns" ng-switch="e.type">
         <span ng-switch-when="text" ng-model="e[c.name]"></span>
         <input ng-switch-when="input" ng-model="e[c.name]"
              ngfocus=... ng-blur=... />
    </td>
</tr>
```

i.e., each row shows one entity, the columns correspond with its properties and the representation depends on the column type.

In case of `c.type=="input"`, an input box gets shown. The entities may be sorted according to any column, this sorting happens automatically and my problem occurs when the selected column is editable. When the value changes, then the rows get reordered, which is pretty confusing for the user.

I could suppress the sorting when an input field is focused, but the problem is that this is practically always the case (as there are hardly any other focusable fields). I wonder if there's a better solution.

Comment: One solution could be to only sort the entities initially or if the users decides to sort them e.g. by clicking on the column header or some similar action. That is, don't sort it automatically.

Comment: What about sorting when an input loses focus?

Comment: Any feedback or suggestions Maartinus?

Comment: @lin Sorry, I hadn't time yet to work on it. I'm perfectly sure, I need this solved; I've read and liked your answer, but there are more pressing problems at the moment. I'll come back to it in a week or two or.... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yea, this happends if you use inline editing. We fighting with this problem too. We created different solutions right now. In your case `ng-blur` should work fine (but I dont know your full application requirements). So you could make it work like in this [runnable demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmhr3888/) which order the data by age.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in data">
     <input type="text" ng-model="item.name" ng-blur="order()">
     <input type="number" ng-model="item.age" ng-blur="order()">
  </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.data = [{
      name: 'Frank',
      age: 28
    },{
      name: 'Peter',
      age: 32
    },{
      name: 'Garry',
      age: 18
    },{
      name: 'Basti',
      age: 24
    },{
      name: 'David',
      age: 102
    },{
      name: 'Magrete',
      age: 76
    },{
      name: 'Sven',
      age: 12
    }];

    $scope.order = function () {
      $scope.data = $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, 'age', true);
    }
});
```